# Problem with colors after converting image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a class which converts images from PNG to JPG (for space saving reasons). My problem is that most of images goes form this[image: before converting] to this. [[image: after]

Currently I found only two pictures that are not affected by conversion [gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tggF5.jpg) but if you're using default windows 10 pictures app windows ignores them when going through pictures. If I open them app behaves like this is only picture in folder even if this isn't true.

```
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

public class PNG2JPG {
     boolean status;

     PNG2JPG(String path,float quality){
        File file = new File(path);

        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
            String fileName = file.getName();
            path = path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf('\\'));
            fileName = fileName.substring(0,fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

            JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = new JPEGImageWriteParam(null);
            jpegParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            jpegParams.setCompressionQuality(quality); //Quality from 0 to 1

            final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
            writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(
                    new File(path + "/" + fileName + ".jpg")));
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), jpegParams);

            status = true;
        }

        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("No file found");
            status = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question might be easier to read if you use less large images (cute dogo btw).

Comment: This looks like you're treating Yuv or YCbCr JPEG images as if they were RGB images. I don't know what `ImageIO.read` does, but I have seen similar colors when reading Yuv as if it were RGB.

Comment: space saving reasons? I dont think so, PNG is small by itself. And if you save JPG to full 100% you'l get an even bigger file -- nonwithstanding this java's conversion is prety junk - you might try some external program and call it from runtime -- if you want to do the conversion

Comment: The problem is the transparency in the PNGs. The Java ImageIO `JPEGImageWriter` will happily write these as 4 channel ARGB JPEGs. However, most other software will unconditionally treat such images as CMYK (or YCCK). And you get this "nice" color effect. If you remove the alpha channel before writing (use `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` or `TYPE_INT_RGB`) it will work fine, and `JPEGImageWriter` will write a standard RGB (as chroma-subsampled YCbCr) file.